# How can I use a column from a subquery in a WHERE condition?

Tags: sum, subquery, where-clause

(select distinct P.PersonID,P.PersonName,(select ISNULL(SUM(CONVERT(decimal(8,1),TotalSum)),0)
as total from Orders SO
where SO.PersonID = P.PersonID AND OrderTypeID = 1 AND total > 0) as tot from Persons P inner join Orders O on P.PersonID = O.PersonID
where P.TypeID = 1000)

hi guys , i need to use total columns in where conditions ,it display invalid  column name

Answer (score -1):

```
(select SUM(CONVERT(decimal(8,1),ISNULL(TotalSum,0))) as total
```

Try this instead.